Apache Beam DataflowRunner Split files into many
I have one large file, also I have header contents file. I will get one input number total parts=(could be 100 or 20 or 200 runtime argument).
Using these, I want to split my largefile to total parts so that each file should have header content available.
Below code is almost generated by Chatgpt, but not able to get output properly. Can anyone explain any help document or correction ?
import org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Sum;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.View;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.GlobalWindow;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollectionView;
import org.joda.time.Instant;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class MySampleFile {

    public interface Options extends PipelineOptions {
        ValueProvider<String> getHeaderFilePath();

        void setHeaderFilePath(ValueProvider<String> value);

        ValueProvider<String> getLargeFilePath();

        void setLargeFilePath(ValueProvider<String> value);

        ValueProvider<Integer> getTotalFileParts();

        void setTotalFileParts(ValueProvider<Integer> value);

        ValueProvider<String> getOutputPath();

        void setOutputPath(ValueProvider<String> value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(Options.class);
        options.setRunner(DirectRunner.class);
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

        // Step 1: Read the header file into a side input
        PCollectionView<List<String>> headerView = pipeline
                .apply("ReadHeaderFile", TextIO.read().from(options.getHeaderFilePath()))
                .apply("HeaderAsList", View.asList());

        // Step 2: Read the large file
        PCollection<String> largeFileLines = pipeline
                .apply("ReadLargeFile", TextIO.read().from(options.getLargeFilePath()));

        PCollectionView<Long> largeFileSizeView = largeFileLines
                .apply("CalculateFileSize", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, Long>() {
                    @ProcessElement
                    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                        String line = c.element();
                        c.output((long) line.getBytes().length);
                    }
                }))
                .apply("SumFileSize", Sum.longsGlobally().asSingletonView());

        // Step 3: Split the large file content into parts and add header
        PCollection<KV<Integer, List<String>>> partitionedContent = largeFileLines
                .apply("PartitionFile", ParDo.of(new PartitionFileFn(options.getTotalFileParts(), headerView, largeFileSizeView))
                        .withSideInputs(headerView, largeFileSizeView));

// Print all the data in the PCollection to System.out.println
        partitionedContent.apply("PrintPartitions", ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<Integer, List<String>>, Void>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                KV<Integer, List<String>> partition = c.element();
                System.out.println("Partition Index: " + partition.getKey());
                for (String line : partition.getValue()) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
        }));

        //Step 4: Write each partitioned file to GCS
        partitionedContent
                .apply("FormatAndWritePartitions", ParDo.of(new WritePartitionFn(options.getTotalFileParts(), options.getOutputPath(), headerView))
                        .withSideInputs(headerView));

        pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }

    static class PartitionFileFn extends DoFn<String, KV<Integer, List<String>>> {
        private final ValueProvider<Integer> totalFileParts;
        private final PCollectionView<List<String>> headerView;
        private final PCollectionView<Long> largeFileSizeView;

        private List<String> currentPartition = new ArrayList<>();
        private int currentPartitionSize = 0;
        private int partitionIndex = 0;
        private long fileSizeInBytes =  0 ;

        public PartitionFileFn(ValueProvider<Integer> totalFileParts, PCollectionView<List<String>> headerView, PCollectionView<Long> largeFileSizeView) {
            this.totalFileParts = totalFileParts;
            this.headerView = headerView;
            this.largeFileSizeView = largeFileSizeView ;
        }

        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            String line = c.element();
            int lineSize = line.getBytes().length;
            fileSizeInBytes = c.sideInput(largeFileSizeView).longValue() ;

            float partitionSizeInBytes = (float)fileSizeInBytes / totalFileParts.get() ;

            if (currentPartitionSize + lineSize > partitionSizeInBytes) {
                // Emit the current partition and reset
                c.output(KV.of(partitionIndex++, new ArrayList<>(currentPartition)));
                currentPartition.clear();
                currentPartitionSize = 0;
            }

            currentPartition.add(line);
            currentPartitionSize += lineSize;
        }

        // Emit any remaining partition at the end of the bundle
        @FinishBundle
        public void finishBundle(FinishBundleContext context) {
            if (!currentPartition.isEmpty()) {
                context.output(KV.of(partitionIndex++, new ArrayList<>(currentPartition)), Instant.now(), GlobalWindow.INSTANCE);
            }
        }
    }

    static class WritePartitionFn extends DoFn<KV<Integer, List<String>>, Void> {
        private final ValueProvider<String> outputPath;
        private final PCollectionView<List<String>> headerView;

        public WritePartitionFn(ValueProvider<Integer> totalParts,ValueProvider<String> outputPath, PCollectionView<List<String>> headerView) {
            this.outputPath = outputPath;
            this.headerView = headerView;
        }

        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
            KV<Integer, List<String>> partition = context.element();
            int partitionIndex = partition.getKey();
            List<String> content = partition.getValue();
            List<String> header = context.sideInput(headerView);

            String outputFileName = outputPath.get() + "/partition-" + partitionIndex + ".txt";
            Path outputPath = Paths.get(outputFileName);

            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    boolean isNewFile = !Files.exists(outputPath) || Files.size(outputPath) == 0;

                    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputPath.toString(), true))) {
                        // Write the header only if the file is new or empty
                        if (isNewFile) {
                            for (String headerLine : header) {
                                writer.write(headerLine);
                                writer.newLine();
                            }
                        }

                        // Write the content
                        for (String line : content) {
                            writer.write(line);
                            writer.newLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error writing to output file: " + outputFileName, e);
            }
        }
    }
}

